# Animating a line while drawing in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

XAML

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" MouseDown="canvas_MouseDown" MouseUp="canvas_MouseUp" Background="White" MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove" />
```

C#

```
Line AnimationLine;
Point P1;
private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    P1 = e.GetPosition(canvas);
    AnimationLine = new Line() { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush { Color = Colors.Blue },StrokeThickness = 3};
    AnimationLine.X1 = P1.X;
    AnimationLine.Y1 = P1.Y;
    canvas.Children.Add(AnimationLine);
}


private void canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var P2 = e.GetPosition(canvas);
    canvas.Children.Remove(AnimationLine);
    //AnimationLine = new Line();
    canvas.Children.Add
      (new Line()
      {
          X1 = P1.X,
          Y1 = P1.Y,
          X2 = P2.X,
          Y2 = P2.Y,
          StrokeThickness = 3,
          Stroke = new SolidColorBrush { Color = Colors.Blue }
      });
}

private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    { 
       var P2 = e.GetPosition(canvas);
       AnimationLine.X2 = P2.X;
       AnimationLine.Y2 = P2.Y;
    }
}
```

i am trying to draw a line first point assigned on mouse down, second point assigned on mouse up and thats when the line gets drawn, but when dragging i want to show the Animation line, animation line which is like a real time guide line.

in order to get it i want to draw a line just like in microsoft paint.

i just wrote the above and it works great, but is this really the way to do it? any built in functionalities that could help?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve, which you haven't explained at all. You've just shown your code to let us guess what it should do. Anyways, to me it seems you are creating a lot more Line objects than actually needed. Why perhaps assign `AnimationLine = new Line()` in `canvas_MouseUp`?

Comment: @Clemens i am trying to draw a line first point assigned on mouse down, second point assigned on mouse up and thats when the line gets drawn, but when dragging i want to show the Animation line, animation line which is like a guide line, in order to get it i want to draw a line just like in microsoft paint, AnimationLine = new Line() so that it gets removed

Comment: @user1492051, try to comment out the code in `canvas_MouseUp` and see if that makes any difference. Also, you check `e.LeftButton` in mouse move handler but not in mouse down handler so right mouse button acts differently (dunno if that\`s intended).

Comment: @icebat it is intended so the mouse move  is just to draw the animation line, the second point for the animation line is in the mouse move and it keeps changing as long as the mouse is not up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could be simplified like shown below. In particular you should add handlers for the `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events instead of the more general `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events. Note also that you would typically [capture the mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx), and that the only purpose for having a mouse up handler is to release the mouse capture.

XAML:

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;

    if (canvas.CaptureMouse())
    {
        var startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        var line = new Line
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            X1 = startPoint.X,
            Y1 = startPoint.Y,
            X2 = startPoint.X,
            Y2 = startPoint.Y,
        };

        canvas.Children.Add(line);
    }
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;

    if (canvas.IsMouseCaptured && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var line = canvas.Children.OfType<Line>().LastOrDefault();

        if (line != null)
        {
            var endPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            line.X2 = endPoint.X;
            line.Y2 = endPoint.Y;
        }
    }
}

private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((Canvas)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```