# Want to draw a line using two mouse clicks in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How do i make it so i can draw a line using two seperate mouse clicks in WPF. Basicly i want to make is so that if i click once nothing happens and when i click a second time a line between the two points appears.

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //Gets the position of the first click
            Point p = e.GetPosition(this);
            double locationX1 = p.X;
            double locationY1 = p.Y;
            
            if (cycle == false) 
            {
                cycle = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Gets the position of the second click
                Point b = e.GetPosition(this);
                double locationX2 = b.X;
                double locationY2 = b.Y;

                //Create a new line
                Line relationBound = new Line();
                relationBound.X1 = locationX1;
                relationBound.Y1 = locationY1;
                relationBound.X2 = locationX2;
                relationBound.Y2 = locationY2;

                //Set color
                SolidColorBrush relationBoundColor = new SolidColorBrush();
                relationBoundColor.Color = Colors.Red;

                //Set thickness
                relationBound.StrokeThickness = 4;
                relationBound.Stroke = relationBoundColor;

                //Add the line to canvas
                CanvasMain.Children.Add(relationBound);
                cycle = false;
            }


       }
```

Comment: Store both coordinatesd of the click event in a property and then create a line eg Shape using these coordinates and add it to a Canvas. or whatever container is appropriate. You can introduce a second property top count the clicks.

Comment: Or even better collect the first coordinate on mouse down and the second on mouse up. This way you don't have to count the clicks. You can also provide a preview line on mouse move.

Comment: As a note, there is no need to explicitly create a SoldColorBrush. Just set `relationBound.Stroke = Brushes.Red;`

Comment: When you draw a preview line as suggest by BionicCode, just make sure you keep the Line in a field after adding it to the Canvas, and update its X2/Y2 values appropriately. Set the field to `null` on MouseUp in order to not draw a Line on MouseMove when not necessary. Or do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21113515/1136211